# windows cmd: searching files with specific path

Tags: windows, cmd

Maybe trivial question but certainly hope someone can help me here..

Windows cmd:

I want to search for files in a root directory and its subdirectories where the files have a parent directory with a specific name. (in this example: \TO).  This parent directory has always the same name but can be another directory (if the path is different)

I tried this but doesn't seem to work: dir \root /b /s *\TO *.java

I also tried to pipe the output of dir to find..  But cannot make 'find' to show the lines containing the desired paths..

Comment: before *.java there should be an additional \

Comment: found what I was looking for:  dir /b /s *.java | findstr /i /C:\to\ > ManualTO.csv

Answer (score 2):

From the cmd prompt:

```
for /r \ %a in (to\*.java) do @echo %a
```

Comment: +1 - Very cool. I was under a false impression that you couldn't include path information within IN() clause when using FOR /R. Glad to now know I was wrong.